# SAS merge only matches first record

Tags: sas

Suppose I have a table A:

```
   sq_id  val
    1       10
    1       10
    2       11
    3       12
```

and table B:

```
sq_id  tor_id
1       999
2       456
3       200
```

And suppose I merge these tables:

```
 proc sort data = A; by sq_id; run;
 proc sort data = B; by sq_id; run;

data mergetable;
  merge A(in=a) B(in=b);
  by sq_id;
  if a =1;
run;
```

The output I get is:

```
   sq_id  val   tor_id
        1   10  999
        1   10
        2   11
        3   12
```

All the other rows do not have any values for tor_id. Are there any reasons for this? I checked that the values have no spaces or blanks.

Comment: Is your expected output where tor_id populated/not missing for every record?

Comment: It should be populated for every record.

Comment: That isn't what happens with your test sample, so you'll need to provide an example that does exhibit the defect.

Comment: Your issue can't be replicated.  See a SAS note on merging one to many files here and what your output should be : http://support.sas.com/kb/24/677.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others noted in the comments, the example you give does not give problematic results. But I'm guessing you are referring to a *many-to-many* type of merge, in which case there **are** problems (for most practical cases) with the data step `merge`.

### Example

```
data a;
  input sq_id val;
  datalines;
1 10
1 11
2 12
3 13
;

data b;
  input sq_id tor_id;
  datalines;
1 999
1 .
2 456
3 200
;

data mergetable;
  merge a (in=a) 
        b (in=b);
  by sq_id;
  if a = 1;
run;

* Results;

sq_id val tor_id 
    1  10    999 
    1  11      . 
    2  12    456 
    3  13    200
```

We see that the first observation from A having `sq_id=1 is matched with the first corresponding observation from B, and that the second observation from A is matched with the second observation from B.

This is rarely (if ever) what we want to happen. As a general rule, whenever there are duplicate values on the matching variable, `proc sql` is to be preferred, because it will always generate all possible combinations.

### Many-to-many joins using `proc sql`

```
proc sql;
  create table mergetable2 as
    select a.*,
           b.tor_id
      from a
        full join b
               on a.sq_id = b.sq_id;
quit;

* Results;

sq_id val tor_id 
    1  10    999 
    1  10      . 
    1  11    999 
    1  11      . 
    2  12    456 
    3  13    200
```

In this case, all observations from A having `sq_id = 1` are matched with **all** observations from B also having `sd_id = 1`.